# How is Leta Lestrange related to Bellatrix Lestrange's husband Rodolphus?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

I know all about how she

> causes the death of her infant brother,

but who is she? Is she Rodolphus Lestrange's sister? How does she link with the HP books?

Answer (score 6):

### Leta Lestrange is Bellatrix Lestrange (née Black)'s distant relative through marriage.

> This year, Zoe has also appeared alongside Scarlett Johansson in the
> comedy Rough Night (which she describes as "so much fun you forget
> you're even being paid"), and is currently filming Fantastic Beasts
> and Where to Find Them 2, which will be released next year. **"I play
> Helena Bonham Carter's great-great aunt.** She's an icon of mine so it's
> a real pinch-me feeling to even be associated with her. I think her
> performance in Fight Club is one of the best by a woman in a film."
>
> <sub><sup>[Zoe Kravitz: 'Beauty can't be defined by race, gender or age'](https://www.independent.ie/entertainment/zoe-kravitz-beauty-cant-be-defined-by-race-gender-or-age-36350899.html)</sup></sub>

That being the case (and based on what we currently know about the two Lestrange bloodlines) this would mean that Leta's great-grandfather was somehow related to [Bellatrix's husband's great-(great?)-grandfather's brother](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/12/1227c32e4c9eccafd355175bcf6174adbb35b9e9120c627d0251b44532e50bf2.jpg), presumably by marriage since the [Corvus Lestrange tree](https://screenrant.com/fantastic-beasts-2-crimes-grindelwald-lestrange-family-tree-explained/) doesn't show a brother.

[image]
<sub><sup>[***FandomWIKIA: Untangling the Lestrange Family Tree***](http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/untangling-the-lestrange-family-tree)</sup></sub>

Comment: It's unlikely Leta is great-great aunt to Bella (same as to Rodolphus) as Leta was born 1897 and Bella was born 1951 (as Pottermore states) - there should be two more generations between them and if my math is correct it is very unlikely unless they all gave birth in very young age, like16. I think Zoe wasn't precise when she told that as she didn't know exactly how many generations separates Leta from Bella

Comment: @ShanaTar - I came up with three possible answers; 1) Zoe Kravitz may have simply been using hyperbole. 2) Wizards live long lives. Who's to say that her relatives in the distant past aren't still extant? 3) JKR done f*%^ed up her maths again

Comment: yeah, for all that reasons it's more believable that Leta is great-aunt or even just aunt to both Bella and Rodolphus

Comment: @ShanaTar - It's been my experience over the years that actors and actresses often just repeat what they've been told about their characters without necessarily understanding that the writer/director was just using a figure of speech. **Actress:** *"How am I related to Bellatrix?*" **Director:** "*She's like your great-great-aunt or something, I guess"* [...later that week...] "**Interviewer:** *How is your character related to Bellatrix?* **Actress:** "*She's my great-great-aunt"*.

Comment: But in TCoG, Yusuf Kama _says_ that Corvus was the last of his (male) bloodline and he was killed. How did the Lestrange name survive and how is Leta related to any other male Lestrange who could be Rodolphus's ancestor? :(

Comment: @Ishita - The last of the line of Corvus Lestrange. Not the last of the Lestrange line per se

Answer (score -1):

Leta Lestrange is definitely from the Lestrange family which makes her a sure relative to Rodolfus Lestrange, though it is not clear how close they are.

She could be his sister (sister by father, as apparently she was the only child of her mother), also she could be Rodolphus's aunt.

We do not know Rodolphus's age - Pottermore doesn't specify that, but can assume he is same age as his wife Bellatrix or older. Could be even much older, as we don't really know how the marriage was arranged. By the time of Harry Potter events Leta would be something around 95 years old.

Therefore it is possible her father had a son younger than Leta was (making her his sister). It makes Bellatrix's husband up to forty years older then she was, but hey, we know it was an arranged marriage after all.

It is also probable Rodolphus is Leta's father's grandson (making Leta his aunt). Both timings fit.

Other then that she doesn't seem to have any connection to the events in Harry Potter books.

Comment: By the time of the _Harry Potter_ events, Leta would be at least 95 years old. Newt was born in 1897, and we see from the new film that he and Leta were at Hogwarts in what looks like more or less the same year. For all we know, Leta may be Rodolphus’ great aunt (or whatever grandparents’ siblings are called – family terminology confuses me). Heck, she may even be Rodolphus’ grandmother; the next films may reveal that she had a child that hadn’t been mentioned in the first two.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, you are right, I did the wrong math here. I think it is very unlikely though she got a child secretly while getting engaged to all Scamander family in turns at the same time :)

Comment: It’s JKR – anything could happen!

Answer (score -1):

While I don't think Leta is Bella's Great-Great Aunt as Zoe once said in an interview because Leta is an only child now that we know her brother died as an infant. It's unclear how she's related to Rodolphus, I'm guessing some sort of distant cousin.

BUT since Leta's grandmother was a Rosier and Bellatrix's mother was a Rosier that makes them related. It's only a distant cousin relation but it's something.

Comment: You should [edit] in your evidence/sources to back this up. At the moment this is a contradicting claim to a partially evidenced answer but with nothing to back it up really.